# send json format to API as a header

Tags: c#, json, ssis

I have responsestring that contains below json data. I have to send all state names each value to REST api. I have used ssis script component. I have to use only JavaScriptSerializer. I can't newton or other json related.

```
  var apifieldurl = some api //i have put some dummy data.
  var stringstate = string.format("{0}/rest/json/getstatesdata?statename= 
  {1}",apifieldurl,statename).
```

My requirement is to send responsestring data to statename (above api field) and get data into table.

responsestring  -

```
 "{\"GetMsg\":{\"CountryName\":
  {\"State\":
  [{\"Obj\":null,\"State\":null,\"desc\":null,\"name\":\"California\"},
  [{\"Obj\":null,\"State\":null,\"desc\":null,\"name\":\"Arizona\"},
  {\"Obj\":null,\"State\":null,\"desc\":null,\"name\":\"Newyork\"}]}}}"
```

Comment: i have written something like this...JavaScriptSerializer jsond = new JavaScriptSerializer(); var result = njsond.Deserialize<list<stateapiresult>>(responstring);      public class stateapiresult { public string statename {get;set;}}                       But Deserialize not working. I'm getting same result in result, which shouldn't be.

Comment: You need to improve this question, please edit your question adding more information about the issue you have and what you want to achieve. In the title you mention headers but in the question body this is never referred to. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand to better ask a question.